# Why does Subscriber have twist_pub?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am referring this book called "Programming with ROS" by  Morgan Quigley.
I am having difficulty understanding this particular code :

```
 Example 8-3. keys_to_twist_using_rate.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
key_mapping = { 'w': [ 0, 1], 'x': [0, -1],
                'a': [-1, 0], 'd': [1, 0],
                's': [ 0, 0] }
g_last_twist = None
def keys_cb(msg, twist_pub):
    global g_last_twist
    if len(msg.data) == 0 or not key_mapping.has_key(msg.data[0]):
       return # unknown key
    vels = key_mapping[msg.data[0]]
    g_last_twist.angular.z = vels[0]
    g_last_twist.linear.x = vels[1]
    twist_pub.publish(g_last_twist)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   rospy.init_node('keys_to_twist')
   twist_pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)
   rospy.Subscriber('keys', String, keys_cb, twist_pub)
   rate = rospy.Rate(10)
   g_last_twist = Twist() # initializes to zero
   while not rospy.is_shutdown():
          twist_pub.publish(g_last_twist)
          rate.sleep()
```

So my question is :

1. Why does `rospy.Subscriber('keys', String, keys_cb, twist_pub)` have `twist_ pub`?
2. What is exactly happening in the while loop ?

   while not rospy.is_shutdown():
   twist_pub.publish(g_last_twist)
   rate.sleep()

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360533/why-does-subscriber-have-twist_pub-?/) by [Zarkzeugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/58734/zarkzeugan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quick summary:

- Every time a message is published on the `keys` topic, the `keys_cb` callback is triggered, and the argument `msg` contains that latest message
- Based on the data in the latest `keys` message, the `keys_cb` updates the value of the global variable `g_last_twist`.
- The while loop you referenced runs at a rate of 10Hz and continually publishes the value of `g_last_twist`
- The callback `keys_cb` is also passed a reference to the `twist_pub` publisher via [the `callback_args` keyword argument](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Subscriber-class.html) in the constructor for a `rospy.Subscriber`. The callback also publishes the latest value of `g_last_twist` using its reference to the `twist_pub`-- presumably so you don't need to wait until the next iteration of the main `while` loop to get the value published.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zarkzeugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/58734/zarkzeugan/) on 2020-08-29**:
So if i understand this correctly
in the if statement, we are first initialising a node
then we are setting `cmd_vel` as a Twist message topic
we are subscribing to the `keys` topic which contains the callback and its argument and the function publishes `g_last_twist`
then we set the rate to 10 Hz so the function runs 10 times in a second and then sleeps for the rest of the time.
then we are initialising `g_last_twist` to 0
and the while loop takes the zero value?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-08-31**:
Yeah. That all sounds about right